# Will CoreData duplicate objects?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an NSManagedObject called "Routine," that has already been saved to my data model. It has a to-many relationship to another NSManagedObject called "Workout". I want to edit the Routine in order to add more workout relationships to it to it.

```
let routine = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Routine
```

The ViewController where I edit the Routine in my data model contains an array of Workout objects:

```
var myWorkouts = [Workout]()
```

Some of the workouts in the "myWorkouts" array may have been already associated with Routine, whereas others may not have (a new workout). I create a relationship between each workout and the routine like this:

```
for workout in myWorkouts {
    routine!.setValue(NSSet(objects: workout), forKey: "workout")
}
```

**My Question:** If a relationship between a Routine and a Workout has already been created, will the above for-loop create a duplicate of that workout to associate with my routine, or will it only create new relationships for previously unassociated workouts?

I hope my questions makes sense. Thanks in advance for the help!

**Routine CoreDataProperties File**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Routine {

    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var workout: Set<Workout>?

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you're working with `Set`s, which means that they only always contain each value once. Therefore, regardless of the enclosing objects (in this case `NSManagedObject`s), there will only be one in there. You're good - re-stating the relationship won't change anything.

I might suggest, however, that you can do a couple of things to make your life easier:

1. If you haven't already, create the concrete subclasses using Xcode's built in tools, so you can directly access relationships and properties.
2. In the concrete subclasses `+NSManagedObjectProperties` file, redefine those to-many relationships from `NSSets?` to `Set<MyClass>?`. This allows you to call Swift-native functions, and works correctly, as `Set` is bridged from `NSSet`.
3. In the future, just call `routine.workout = workout`, which is much clearer than the way your code defines setting the relationship.

Comment: I already did step 1, but 2 and 3 are fantastic suggestions so thank you very much! I'm still getting used to working with updating and adding relationships, so I appreciate the explanation! :D

Comment: You're welcome! And, on step 3, in general, it's always much more sane (and I got it backwards the first time), to make calls to store things on the to-one side.

Comment: Awesome! So if I understand correctly, I just change the garbled mess of routine!.setvalue... to routine.workout = workout

Comment: I'm actually a little unclear about how exactly your data model is structured and what you're trying to define based on your code (and is your code one-to-many or many-to-many), but if you want to assign a mess of routines to a workout, you can say workout.routines = Set(routines) or enumerate through routines and call routine.workout = routine.

Comment: So I'm trying to define a mess of workouts to a routine, I ran into one problem with your routine.workout = workout solution....It said I can't assign value of type "Workout" to type Set<Workout>....The solution was type casting and the final product ended up being 
routine.workout = Set(arrayLiteral: workout)

Comment: I updated my code to show my coredataproperties file for the Routine object. I also put a screen shot of my data model up there if you're curious. Thanks again!